# Dell Latitude D-series - battery LED blinks orange 3 times

Tags: laptop, power-supply, battery, dell-latitude

**My Dell Latitude D530 battery LED blinks orange 3 times, then turns green for a while and then again - blinks orange 3 times... over and over. What does it mean?**

I found [this advice on the dell.com](https://www.dell.com/support/article/cz/cs/czdhs1/sln155342/diagnostic-and-battery-indicators-for-dell-latitude-notebooks-and-tablets?lang=en), which says: "Flashing orange — The battery charge is low". This doesn't make much sense though, because my laptop is plugged in (charged using a power cable connected to 230V socket).

---

PS: How it happened: I experimented with external battery and probably did a shortcut accidentally on the external battery. The ext. battery completely discharged and the laptop turned off. Then I unplugged the external battery's power cable, plugged the 230V socket power charging cable and turned on the computer. Then the blinking started and it's still going on even after like 10 minutes. The computer seems to work normally.

Comment: You damaged the battery charging circuit in the laptop.

Comment: What do you mean you performed a shortcut accidentally on the external battery?  Do you mean you created a short with the external battery?

Comment: @Ramhound: the wires of the power cable between ext. battery and laptop were not isolated properly and might have created a shortcut

Comment: Ad the close vote. Unclear what I am asking? Pardon?? The question stands there in bold, for it to be even more obvious!

Answer (score 0):

If you had done nothing, it would indicate the battery needs to be replaced.  Normal with age.

Now the external battery may have possibly damaged the charging circuit.

You may now wish to visit a local computer store to have them diagnose hardware faults

Comment: Thanks John. *"If you had done nothing, it would indicate the battery needs to be replaced"* What does the diagnostic signal mean then, precisely? Do you have any reference?

Comment: It likely indicates a low battery (not charging fully) but could also indicate a hardware issue